# UIAppearence only working with system colors in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am trying to change the color of the navigation bars in my app with UIAppearance.

But only when I use a system color, it works:

```
    UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];

    [navigationBarAppearance setBarTintColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:220.0f green:47.0f blue:40.0f alpha:100.0f]]; // does not work

    [navigationBarAppearance setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220.0f green:47.0f blue:40.0f alpha:100.0f]]; // does not work

    [navigationBarAppearance setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // works
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should've read the docs for `UIColor`. The methods you are using accept a value between 0.0 and 1.0, not 0.0 and 255.0.

Comment: @duci9y You are right. Unfortanately you did post as comment instead of answer, so I have to accept Fry's answer, although he posted later than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method

```
colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:
```

accept four value between `0.0` and `1.0`. So if you have the components from `0.0` to `255.0` you need to normalize with a division by `255.0f`.

```
[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:220.0f/255.0f green:47.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:100.0f/255.0f]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing wrong with custom color method, its like this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:127.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```